# default CRUD in vaadin 7 on grails

Tags: grails, vaadin7

First of all, I am new to both Grails and Vaadin, I'm trying to make it work according to docs. I am using Grails 2.2.4 and Vaadin 7.1.8.2.  I installed the plugin using:

> $ grails install-plugin vaadin 7.1.8.2

and put the plugin into BuildConfig.groovy:

> compile ':vaadin:7.1.8.2'

I have made a basic Vaadin UI that works (even generated from Eclipse designer - great stuff), I can modify it and it auto-reloads. Fine. I got the URL mapping set in VaadinConfig.groovy so that I can use the traditional Grails CRUD controllers as well as my Vaadin UI:

```
mapping = [
        "/vaadin": "app.MyUI"
]
contextRelativePath = "/vaadin"
```

I was hoping I could use the Vaadin-style CRUD scaffolding of domain classes as in http://mckenfra.github.io/grails-vaadin-plugin/source-code/docs/ref/Command%20Line/generate-vaadin-all.html but I can't generate it:

```
$ grails generate-vaadin-all "*" 
| Script 'GenerateVaadinAll' not found, did you mean:
1) GenerateAll
2) GenerateViews
3) GenerateController
4) DbmGenerateChangelog
5) DbmGenerateGormChangelog
```

I'm getting the same if I try generate-vaadin-views or generate-vaadin-controllers. What could I be doing wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try RefreshDependencies before GenerateVaadinAll.

Comment: Thanks Alessandro. Unfortunately, no go: clean + refresh-dependencies = no change. Grails still doesn't know what generate-vaadin-all means.